# MATLAB song recognizer has bad performance

Tags: matlab

So this is my code for a MATLAB program that works like this:

I have a folder with 10 .mp3 songs ( `/songs` ) and a folder with test files ( `/tests` ).
Test are just 10s cutouts of songs from the `/songs` folder

What I do is:

1) move to songs dir, and load songs into a list

```
cd(path_to_songs_dir)
songList = dir('*.mp3');
numSongs= numel(songList);

for i=1:numSongs
    [y{i}, fs{i}] = audioread(songList(i).name);
end
```

2) load test file

```
[y_test, fs_test] = audioread(path_to_test_file);
```

3) create a gallery for the graphs

```
for t=1:numSongs
  gallery{t}=y{t}(:,1);
end
```

4) use cross correlation to determine which song has the highest cross correlation value with my test file

```
for g=1:numSongs
  [xc{g},lagc{g}]= xcorr(gallery{g},y_test(:,1),'none');
  if g == 1
    [maxcorr,maxli] = max(xc{g});
    n_song = g;
  elseif g ~= 1 && max(xc{g}) > maxcorr
    [maxcorr,maxli] = max(xc{g});
    n_song = g;
  end
end
```

The program works just fine and is pretty good at recognizing songs, but it is **excruciatingly** slow. It may take up to an entire minute, and it only has to compare the test againt 10 songs.

Any idea to make it faster? Any kind of suggestion on improving the code is appreciated, this is one of my very first attempts to use MATLAB

Comment: You should probably pre-compute the FFT of each of your songs. The `xcorr` function uses the FFT internally, thus is the most expensive part of your program. To make it really fast you need a wholly different approach though. This would probably involve computing features of sections of each of your songs, at least to narrow down which “type” of song it is, so you only need to compare to that category of song.

Comment: Also, I would divide up the song database into overlapping 10s fragments, and do cross-correlation with each of those. Pre-compute FFT of those fragments, then for each input sample you compute one FFT, multiply with each of your database, and determine power (high xcorr implies high power in FFT, I believe).